# Groovy script issue with escaping quotes

Tags: amazon-web-services, groovy, escaping, amazon-dynamodb, groovyshell

I'm running this shell command using groovy (which worked in bash):

```
aws --profile profileName --region us-east-1 dynamodb update-item --table-name tableName --key '{"group_name": {"S": "group_1"}}' --attribute-updates '{"attr1": {"Value": {"S": "STOP"},"Action": "PUT"}}'
```

This updates the value of an item to `STOP` in DynamoDB. In my groovy script, I'm running this command like so:

```
String command = "aws --profile profileName --region us-east-1 dynamodb update-item --table-name tableName --key '{\"group_name\": {\"S\": \"group_1\"}}' --attribute-updates '{\"attr1\": {\"Value\": {\"S\": \"STOP\"},\"Action\": \"PUT\"}}'"
println(command.execute().text)
```

When I run this with `groovy afile.groovy`, nothing is printed out and when I check the table in DynamoDB, it's not updated to `STOP`. There is something wrong with the way I'm escaping the quotes but I'm not sure what. Would appreciate any insights.

Sidenote: When I do a simple aws command like `aws s3 ls` it works and prints out the results so it's something with this particular command that is throwing it off.

Comment: Have you tried different Groovy delimiters? ie: `String command = $/aws --profile profileName --region us-east-1 dynamodb update-item --table-name tableName --key '{"group_name": {"S": "group_1"}}' --attribute-updates '{"attr1": {"Value": {"S": "STOP"},"Action": "PUT"}}'/$`

Comment: ^Yeah, that gives me the same thing. It executes, but the table isn't updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't quote for groovy (and the underlying exec) -- you would have to quote for your shell.  The `execute()` on a String does not work like a shell - the underlyting code just splits at whitespace - any quotes are just passed down as part of the argument.

Use `["aws", "--profile", profile, ..., "--key", '{"group_name": ...', ...].execute()` and ignore any quoting.

And instead of banging strings together to generate JSON, use `groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson([group_name: [S: "group_1"]])`